# Store the values from one fragment and retrive in other

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments named Personal_info,contact_info and professional_info.When my app starts personal info is shown by default.In personal_info the user fills all the info and when he clicks on the continue button the next fragment that is contact_info should be displayed.Also in contact_info the user fills all the details and when he clicks continue,professional_info should open up.Now in the last fragment that is profession_info i haved called a web services which sends all the info to the server.My questions is

1)How to call contact_info from personal_info as both of them are fragments.

2)How to get the values from personal_info frag and contact_info frag into professional_info.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends MainFragment {

    private FrameLayout container;
    private TextView headerid;
    FragmentManager manager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.main);
        initialize ();

    }


    private void initialize() {

        container = (FrameLayout) findViewById (R.id.container);
        headerid = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.header_id);
//        manager=getFragmentManager ();
//        transaction=manager.beginTransaction ();
//        PersonalInfo info=new PersonalInfo ();
//        transaction.add (R.id.container,info,"personal_info");
//        transaction.commit ();
        MainFragment.startFragment (new PersonalInfo (),true);
    }
}
```

Personal_info.Java

```
public class PersonalInfo extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    View view;
    //    private EditText etfirstname;
    private EditText etlastname;
    private Spinner spgender;
    private Spinner spage;
    private Spinner spnationality;
    private Spinner sprelegion;
    private Button btcontinue1;
    private LinearLayout personalinfo;
    private static String first_name, last_name, gender, age, nationality, religion;
    private String[] gender_array;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> gender_str;
    private Context c = getActivity ();
    private String[] religion_array;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> religion_str;
    private String[] state_array;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> state_str;
    private String[] age_array;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> age_str;
    private String[] nationality_array;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> nationality_str;
    private String str_gender;
    private String[] gender_code;
    private String str_religion, gender_id, religion_id;
    private String[] religion_code;
    private String str_age;
    private String age_substring;
    private String str_nationality;
    private String[] nationality_code;
    private String nationality_id;
    private Button btcontinue1;
    private Spinner spgender;
    private EditText etfirstname;
    private EditText etlastname;
    private Spinner spage;
    private Spinner spnationality;
    private Spinner sprelegion;
    TextView header;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.personal_info_frag, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        initialize ();
//        spinnerSetup ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void spinnerSetup() {


//        gender_array = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Gender);
//        Arrays.sort (gender_array, 1, gender_array.length);
//        //gender_str = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, R.layout.textview_spinner, gender_array);
//        gender_str.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
//        spgender.setAdapter (gender_str);

        religion_array = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Religion);
        Arrays.sort (religion_array, 1, religion_array.length);
        religion_str = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, R.layout.textview_spinner, religion_array);
        religion_str.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sprelegion.setAdapter (religion_str);

        age_array = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Age);
        Arrays.sort (age_array, 1, age_array.length);
        age_str = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, R.layout.textview_spinner, age_array);
        age_str.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spage.setAdapter (age_str);

        nationality_array = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Nationality);
        nationality_str = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, R.layout.textview_spinner, nationality_array);
        nationality_str.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spnationality.setAdapter (nationality_str);


    }

//    private void initialize() {
//
//        etfirstname = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.et_first_name);
//        etlastname = (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.et_last_name);
//        spgender = (Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.sp_gender);
//        spage = (Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.sp_age);
//        spnationality = (Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.sp_nationality);
//        sprelegion = (Spinner)view.findViewById (R.id.sp_relegion);
//        btcontinue1 = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.bt_continue_1);
//        btcontinue1.setOnClickListener (this);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        first_name = etfirstname.getText ().toString ();
        last_name = etlastname.getText ().toString ();

        str_gender = (String) spgender.getSelectedItem ();//gender value
        gender_code = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Gender_id);
        gender_id = gender_code[spgender.getSelectedItemPosition ()];// gender code


        //for religion
        str_religion = (String) sprelegion.getSelectedItem ();
        religion_code = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Religion_Code);
        religion_id = religion_code[sprelegion.getSelectedItemPosition ()];

        str_age = (String) spage.getSelectedItem ();
        age_substring = str_age.substring (0, 2).trim ();

        //for nationality
        str_nationality = (String) spnationality.getSelectedItem ();
        nationality_code = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Nationality_code);
        nationality_id = nationality_code[spnationality.getSelectedItemPosition ()];




    }
```

MainFragment.Java

```
public class MainFragment extends Activity {

    Context mContext;
    public static FragmentManager fManager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initialize();



    }


    private void initialize() {
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        fManager = getFragmentManager ();
    }

    public static void startFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean isToBackStack) {

        /*
         * Restricting Fragment transition if same fragment available in top of
         * BackStack.
         *
         * If tempFragment is Null it means there is no fragment was added yet.
         */

        Fragment tempFragment = fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        if (tempFragment != null && tempFragment.getClass().getName().equals(fragment.getClass().getName())) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Actual transition of Fragment
         */

        FragmentTransaction fragt = fManager.beginTransaction();
//        fragt.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_out_right,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        fragt.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

        // hide background fragment
        fragt.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        if (isToBackStack)
            fragt.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
        fragt.commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: better to go with a common singleton class,from current frag just set the value and  get where ever you want using getinstance.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to let the activity that created the fragments, be the one facilitating the communication.

If we have an activity A I let it implement an interface that can be used by the fragments. When the fragment is done, and want to send data, it calls the activity on the interface. It is then the activity that opens the next fragment and gives it the required values.

It could be something like this:

```
interface InformationInterface {
   public void informationGathered(Map<String,String> personalInformation);
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements InformationInterface {
   ...lifeCycleMethods...

   public void informationGathered(Map<String,String> personalInformation) {
      //Start the next fragment, giving it the personalInformation
   }
}

//Then in the fragment, we get the interface of the activity
public class PersonalInfoFragment extends Fragment {
   private InformationInterface callback;

   ...lifecycleMethods...

   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if (activity instanceof InformationInterface) {
        this.callback = (InformationInterface)activity;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity doesn't have InformationInterface");
    }
}

private void next() {
   //Called when user presses next
   callback.informationGathered(...map with required values...);
}
```

This way the interfaces does not need to know of each other and the activity is responsible for all communication between them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: That is indeed the standard and recommended way of doing things.

Comment: Anything you can send around you can use, but the communication should go from fragment -> activity - > fragment.